# Python extract variable in if statement and have checks

Tags: python, if-statement

Is the below code valid in python or its not possible to extract variable in python and perform checks on it in one line?

```py
def method1(self,some_text):
   """For illustration purpose it returns a hard coded value"""
   return (1,2)

if x = method1("Hello") and x[0] == 1 and x[1] = 2:
   print("This is it {},{}".format(x[0],x[1]))
elif x = method1("World") and x[0] == 3 and x[1] = 4:
   print("This is it, second {},{}".format(x[0],x[1]))
elif x = method1("The") and x[0] == 5 and x[1] = 6:
   print("This is it, third {},{}".format(x[0],x[1]))
else:
   print("No match")
```

Currently I have this if condition for multiple attribute to check. Since python throws error because its not a valid syntax, I have to declare all such property above the if statement and so many attributes being declared in the local block.

Any better way or suggestion, to have extract the variable and have checks in one line as well as use the attribute within if block?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
def method1(some_text):
   """For illustration purpose it returns a hard coded value"""
   return (1,2,3)

def printres(x):
    for i in x:
        res=method1(i[0])
        if res[:2]==i[1]:
            print(i[2].format(res[2]))
            return
    else:
        print("No match")
        
        

printres([("Hello",(1,2),"This is it {}"),("World",(3,4),"This is it, second {}"),("The",(4,5),"This is it, third {}")])
```

Comment: Whole idea is to extract variable and use It to check and print , like x[0] and x[1]. it could be tuple returning 3 values, where we might use x[0] and x[1] for validation but use x[2] to print the actual message.

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: Check the cleaner version